# Pass variable from a VF page to a controller

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, commandbutton

I'm new to visualforce programming and I would appreciate your advice on this matter.

Basically, I'm trying to create a dynamic VF page that will change its content when a button is clicked.
My VF page gets a list of custom objects called project__c and I would like to let the user dynamically choose which list of projects he wants to view.

So I though of creating a button that will change the following line of code:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!projectList1}" var="item">
```

to:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!projectList2}" var="item">
```

Can anyone explain on the overall process and how could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've barely included any code, but the easiest way to do this is to have a "currentList" instead:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!currentList}" var="item">
```

And in your controller:

```
public void switchToList1() {
    currentList = projectList1;
}
public void switchToList2() {
    currentList = projectList2;
}
```

A reference to another list costs virtually no memory.